# Stored procedure with Select query returns result in SMSS but not with C# call

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I've been working on converting some old code and in this case, one piece had some hard coded SQL statements that I want to move to stored procedures. However upon testing, I'm not getting any results when called from C# but if I execute directly in SMSS, I do get results...

I'm stumped..

This is the C# code:

```
using (SqlCommand ExistingIDCommand = new SqlCommand("RetrieveExistingApplicants", connection))
{
       ExistingIDCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
       ExistingIDCommand.Parameters.Add("@Applicant_Client_ID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Applicant.Applicant_Client_ID;    

       using (SqlDataReader rdrDoesIDExist = ExistingIDCommand.ExecuteReader())
       {
           while (rdrDoesIDExist.Read())
           {
               boolDuplicate = true;
               Applicant.Asta_ID = string.IsNullOrEmpty(rdrDoesIDExist.GetString(0)) ? "" : rdrDoesIDExist.GetString(0).Trim();
           }
       }
}
```

And the query itself is very simple:

```
SELECT Applicant_Client_ID, ASTA_ID 
FROM AY_Applicant_Application_FULL_DATA
WHERE Applicant_Client_ID = @Applicant_Client_ID
```

I'm trying to look for duplicate values and in cases where there is a duplicate, I have to do an update with some particular logic while if there is no dupe, then i need to do an insert with specific logic.

But when I run this in C#, even IDs that are dupes are returning no results... I'm lost.

Appreciate any help here!

Comment: What is the actual database type of `Applicant_Client_ID`? I know you define it as varchar in your SqlCommand, but if the database is different, that could be your issue.

Comment: Please show us where `Applicant` is declared and instantiated.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain you're running your code against the same database that your SSMS is connected to?

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by creating List and in list i'm doing something similar code is below check this

```
List<Test> TestList = new List<Test>();
Test test;

while (reader.Read())
{
    test = new Test();
    test.ID = int.Parse(reader["ID"].ToString());
    test.Name = reader["Name"].ToString();
    TestList.Add(test);
}

gvGrid.DataSource = TestList;
gvGrid.DataBind();
```